# I am trying to call the number of passengers to print

Tags: java, static, abstract

I am trying to figure out the differences when trying to print something to the screen by calling on a specific method. Also, could someone explain the difference between static, public, and abstract classes?

Here is my code:

```
public class Vehicle {
    int maxSpeed;
    int wheels;
    int passengers;
    String color;
    double fuelCapacity;  

    void horn() {
        System.out.println("Honk!");
    }
}

public void passengers() {
    System.out.println(passengers);
}

class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle v3 = new Vehicle();
        v1.color = "Burnt Orange";
        v2.horn();
        v3.passengers = 3;
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't think "explain the difference between static, public, and abstract classes," is a reasonable request of SO. There are lots of free online resources that already exist to explain that

Comment: Could you elaborate on the first part of your question? I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: "_figure out the differences when trying to print something to the screen by calling on a specific method_" As opposed to what other approach? How would you print without calling a method?

Comment: `Vehicle` has a member variable named `passengers` and a member function with the same name. After setting `v3.passengers = 3;` you need to call the function to print it `v3.passengers();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Static Classes**
Static classes are basically a way of grouping classes together in Java. Java doesn't allow you to create top-level static classes.Only you can created is nested (inner) static classes.

**Public Classes**
In a given Java file only a one public class can be there. In other words the java file must be saved using the public class name with .java extension. Also in a given file there can be any number of non public (default) classes.

**Abstract Classes**
These classes cannot be instantiated. That means cannot make objects using theses classes. Because these classes can have abstract methods. They don't have an implementation therefore these classes extend by another class and implement all the abstract methods. (If that class is not an abstract class.)

Comment: Abstract classes can have implementations.